# Read multiple excel files from azure blob storage in PySpark efficiently

Tags: excel, databricks, pyspark

I am reading multiple excel files from azure blob storage in databricks using following pyspark script

```
schema1 = StructType([
 StructField("c1", StringType(), True)
,StructField("c2", StringType(), True)
...
,StructField("c19", StringType(), True)
,StructField("c20", StringType(), True)])

df_full = None
objects = dbutils.fs.ls(mount_pt + "/" + blob)

for x in objects:   # reading each file
  value = list(x)
  file_name = value[1]
  sample_df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").schema(schema1).option("header", "false").option("dataAddress", "0!A3").load(mount_pt + "/" + blob + "/" + file_name)
  if sample_df.count() == 1: continue #skip empty files
  if df_full is None: #first non empty file
      df_full = sample_df.drop_duplicates()
  else:
      df_full  = df_full.union(sample_df).drop_duplicates()
```

I am counting each sample_df and if it doesn't contain any row then union is skipped. However, executing above code is taking more than 2 hours (even more as I had to stop execution in between). There are appx 450 files having varying number of rows from 0 to 65K appx. Appx 60 percent of excel files are empty.

Even when I read a file with appx 30K rows, it is taking appx 2 min to display first 1000 records.

Is there any other way through which I can read data faster and save it in a single dataframe or any way through which existing code can be optimized to read data faster.

Thanks!

Comment: total size of the folder containing excel files is appx 2.4GB

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all sheets to CSV files, can be automated using pandas for this, so that we can read all files simultaneously and very quickly. No need to execute in a loop and can skip the filenames too.

Comment: It will fail if excel has some comma-separated data in a column.